# How to create a SQL file with inserts to multiple tables with linked IDs?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, bulkinsert

I have a PHP program that does a series of DB inserts into several tables.

A requirement was raised for the program to generate a SQL dump of the inserts it does, so that they can be inserted into another DB. (this second database has the same schema, but different data).

Generating the SQL dump is easy: Just output the query strings as they're executed.

However, because we're doing inserts into several tables, with cross-referenced ID fields, the SQL generated this way contain fixed ID values for the foreign key fields.

ie a sample of the dump file might look like this:

```
insert into tableA  ....
insert into tableB  .... id_a = 365 ....
insert into tableC  .... id_b = 1895, id_a = 365 ....
```

...where "365" and "1895" are populated into the queries by PHP calling `$mysqli->insert_id` to get the ID of the record inserted into the previous table.

So this represents an accurate picture of the queries that were executed to insert the data into the DB.

The problem is that these fixed ID values are obviously not going to be correct when the SQL dump is run on the second database. When the first record is inserted into tableA on the second DB, the ID of the resulting record will not be 365, and thus since the subsequent inserts into tableB and tableC contain fixed references to that ID, they will be inserted with their foreign keys pointing to the wrong records.

How can I solve this problem?

Is there a way I can generate a SQL dump of this type that references other inserts in the same query dump but without having fixed IDs?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may first try insert data then create the reference constraints ALTER TABLE. There is INSERT IGNORE which continues to insert data into table even after an error. So only the conflicting values are not populated into table.